# How to solve AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, sha256

I tried to give validation to the give form in the HTML file using JAVASCRIPT and also check the email is available or not in the database table using AJAX.Also imported sha256 from hashlib.But I got an error like this. I did not understand why this error happens.Can anyone suggests a solution for this problem.

```
Internal Server Error: /User/Registration/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\salon\user\views.py", line 214, in userregister
    epassword = sha256(upassword.encode()).hexdigest()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{% static 'styles/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function getsid(str)
        {   print(str)
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                 if(xmlhttp.readystate==4 &&  xmlhttp.status==200)
                 {
                    document.getElementById("lemail").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
                 }
           }
             xmlhttp.open("GET","{% url 'checkemail' %}?id="+str,true);
             xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <section class="sreg" id="sreg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="htop">
                <h4>User <span>Register Form</span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                        <form method="POST" name="contact" action="{% url 'userregister' %}">
                             {%csrf_token%}
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                                    <span id="lfname"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    <span id="llname"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="email">Email</label>
                                 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onchange="getsid(this.value)">
                                 <span id="lemail"></span>
                             </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                                <span id="lpass"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpassword" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                <span id="lcpass"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile">
                                 <span id="lmob"></span>
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="address">Address</label>
                                 <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address" rows="3" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                                 <span id="laddress"></span>
                             </div>
                             <center>
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return userregister()">Submit</button>
                              </center>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/scriptfunction.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def userregister(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    ufname = request.POST.get('fname')
    ulname = request.POST.get('lname')
    uemail = request.POST.get('email')
    upassword = request.POST.get('password')
    ucpassword=request.POST.get('cpassword')
    epassword = sha256(upassword.encode()).hexdigest()
    umobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
    uaddress = request.POST.get('address')

    if (clientreg.objects.filter(Email=uemail).exists()):
        messages.info(request, "Email ID Already Taken")
        return redirect('userregister')
    elif (upassword!=ucpassword):
        messages.info(request, "Password Doesn't Match")
        return redirect('userregister')
    elif (clientreg.objects.filter(Mobile=umobile).exists()):
        messages.info(request, "Mobile Number Already Taken")
        return redirect('userregister')

    else:
        cloginobj = clientlogin()
        cloginobj.Username = uemail
        cloginobj.Password = epassword
        cloginobj.save()

        cuserreg = clientreg()
        cuserreg.Login_id = cloginobj
        cuserreg.First_name = ufname
        cuserreg.Last_name = ulname
        cuserreg.Email = uemail
        cuserreg.Password = epassword
        cuserreg.Mobile = umobile
        cuserreg.Address = uaddress
        cuserreg.save()
        userdetails = clientlogin.objects.get(Username=uemail, Password=epassword)
        cid = userdetails.id
        request.session['cid'] = cid
        return redirect("userhome")

else:
    return render(request, "userregister.html")


def checkemail(request):
useremail = request.GET["id"]
count=clientlogin.objects.filter(Username=useremail).count()
if count==0:
    return HttpResponse("Email Id is available")
else:
    return HttpResponse("Email Id already exist")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('User/Registration/', views.userregister, name="userregister"),
    path('User/Registration/CheckEmail', views.checkemail, name="checkemail"),    
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `upassword` it seems to be None.

```
 upassword = request.POST.get('password')
```

It seems post data does not have a `password`. You can check if that value if being passed from POST request.

Once of the way to handle is:

```
try:
    upassword = request.POST['password']
except KeyError:
    // password value not passed in POST request
    // return HTTPResponse with 400 code
```

Comment: When i run this code,post data does not have a password.How can I pass password in POST request? @navyad

Comment: When I use 'required' for validation instead of using onclick function,it works.